# How to get value of other column cell but same row in ag-grid Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, grid, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to get the values of the other column cell but the same row in ag-grid angular. I want to access this value in a different column. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `api.forEachNode` to iterate through all the nodes in the grid, and add logic to search for the node you want. Then you can access the data for the row by accessing `node.data`.

See the documentation example that uses `api.forEachNode`: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/row-selection/#example-using-foreachnode

Answer (score 0):

Use [ValueGetter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/value-getters/) in ColDef:

```
[
  { field: 'a' },
  { field: 'b' },
  {
    colId: 'a&b',
    headerName: 'A + B',
    valueGetter: params => params.data.a + params.data.b
  }
]
```

You can also use [Expressions](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-expressions/):

```
valueGetter: 'data.a + data.b'
```